# How to query number of input based on minute in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-queryset

So i'm implementing a webapps for a local trucking rental SME. basically what it does is it logs date, hour and minutes to count the Ritase(the output) of the truck.

here is models.py

```
class Muatan(models.Model):
     recorded_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
     date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)

     shift  = models.ForeignKey(Shift, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

     time_logged = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False)

     excavator = models.ForeignKey(Excavator, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
     operator_excavator = models.ForeignKey(ExcavatorOperator, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)


     dumpTruck = models.ForeignKey(DumpTruck, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
     driver_dumptruck = models.ForeignKey(DumpTruckDriver, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

     location = models.ForeignKey(Lokasi, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
     material = models.ForeignKey(Material, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)



     reported_problem = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

to give an example from the models, suppose that the manager logs these input from admin.py. simplified for question purposes, i only put date_added and time_logged.

- august 13, 2018 at 14:20
- august 13, 2018 at 14:40
- august 13, 2018 at 14:59
- august 13, 2018 at 15:15
- august 13, 2018 at 15:30

the expected output from the query would be something like

- hour: 14 mins: 20
- hour: 14 mins: 40
- hour: 14 mins: 59
- total ritase: 3

because there are 3 logs within the hour 14.

how would i implement this in django? also, do i put the code in models.py or views.py? total django noobs here, really appreciate your help SO :)

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find the answer after digging to the documentation. it uses the `TruncHour` function

```
muatan.objects.annotate(hour=TruncHour('time_logged', output_field=TimeField()),).values('hour').annotate(muatan=Count('id'))
```